# can we create index in excel as in sql for quick search

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have **jumbled attribute values** in columns C, D, E, F of **sheet1**. 
I have **arranged data** in **sheet2**.

I need to

- compare **sheet1** and **sheet2**
- if any row in sheet1 matches with sheet2 then need to inset 'TRUE' in `status` column

I have concatenated values A to F in **sheet1** and in **sheet2**.

With `Vlookup` I am able to obtain which is in the right order.

I have 500 000 records in both the sheets and the *operation is very slow*. I don't have access to SQL Server.  How can I boost the search.  Can we create Index in excel as in SQL?

```
Noun        Modifier        C           D              E                  F           Status
Abrasive     Any         Type         Width            Length           Material       TRUE
Abrasive     Belt        Width        Length           Material         Type           FALSE
Abrasive     Disc        Type         Width            Length           Material       TRUE
Battery      Any         Type         Voltage          Current Type     Current        TRUE
Battery      Dry Cell    Type         Material         Amp Hours        Construction   FALSE
Battery      Gel cell    Type         Material         Current Type     Voltage        TRUE
Bearing      Any         Bore Type    Inside Diameter  Outside Diameter Radius         TRUE
Bearing      Ball        Cage MaterialStyle            Radial Clearance Series         TRUE
Bearing      Cone        Radius       Type             Inside Diameter  Width          FALSE
```

Comment: Are you trying to match records with Excel or VBA?

Comment: The answer is no... Unfortunately for you

Comment: Have you maybe got Access? Most of the variations of Microsoft Office seem to come with that, and it can handle this sort of thing perfectly well. But, no, not happening in Excel.

Comment: Yes, I can use Access. It will help.